# $GL(E)$ is connected in $L(E)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Why $GL(E)$ is connected in $L(E)$ when $\dim E = \infty$?

Answer (score 2):

This is not always true for all Banach spaces $E$. However, if for example $E$ is an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space, then $GL(E)$ is connected and even contractible, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=10aaeB1ojfkC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=show+that+GL(E)+is+connected+in+L(E)+for+infinite-dimensional+E&source=bl&ots=q6_a-3Yth0&sig=ACfU3U3NLk5z0rYF-eMIXeFNaw0h1mFF1w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix5N3Ot-viAhU5i8MKHRALBEkQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20GL(E)%20is%20connected%20in%20L(E)%20for%20infinite-dimensional%20E&f=false).

Comment: If E is a Banach space of infinite dimensional not a separable Hilbert space. Why $GL(E)$ is connected in $L(E)$ ?

Comment: There are counterexamples, it is not true in general. Did you read the link?

Comment: yes, I did read the link. It was very helpful.